# Finding duplicate values with common denominator in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find duplicate values on an Oracle Db table that have a common denominator. The table is very big and contains many addresses for many countries, by checking a few of the cities I have seen many duplicate zones (neighbourhoods, districts) under the same city, so i need to list all duplicate zones that are under the same city (same post code etc.).

I have already tried many of the queries found on StackOverflow, no success yet.

For example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE1
WHERE
    SYNONYM = '1'
    AND STATE = 'ENGLAND'
    AND DISTRICT IN (
        SELECT DISTRICT
    FROM
        TABLE1
    GROUP BY
        DISTRICT
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Basically i need to find record a and record b where nation/state/city/postcode are the same and output both.

To simplify:

MyTable: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O.

Find all records where C, D, E AND F ARE THE SAME. Show all records where this happens.

C, D and E are numbers, F is a description (CHAR)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly group by those columns, and look for `COUNT(*)` is more than `1` :

```
SELECT NATION, STATE, CITY, POSTCODE
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY NATION, STATE, CITY, POSTCODE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Edit :** considering your last update try with `trim()` function for the string type column which may have heading or trailing spaces :

```
SELECT C, D, E, trim(F) as F
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY C, D, E, trim(F)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, checked query results manually and there are no duplicate districts within them.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it a little and it seems to be what I'm looking for! :)

SELECT C, D, E, F, COUNT(F) 
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY C, D, E, F
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: you're welcome @AdamH. Did you evaluate count(F) of trim(F) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
SELECT
  NATION, STATE, CITY, POSTCODE
FROM
  TABLE1
GROUP BY
  (NATION + STATE + CITY + POSTCODE), NATION, STATE, CITY, POSTCODE
HAVING
  COUNT(NATION + STATE + CITY + POSTCODE) > 1
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either, checked your query results manually and there are no duplicate districts within these cities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the records, use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by c, d, e, f) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

If you just want the `c`/`d`/`e`/`f` values, then aggregation is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this but with no luck, maybe I am doing something wrong.

This is the error I get:
     ORA-00936: espressione mancante
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @AdamH . . . There is no missing expression in this query.  Here is a db<>fiddle that illustrates that the code works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9f9d5f4ee371818b8ae1a2f8cd7769a.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, I've tried again and the code does in fact work, but, the results displayed are similar, not identical. I'm getting the same district names but they are displayed even if they are in different cities, i.e. North in London, North in Manchester. This although the city is part of the query (as are the Nation and State/Region).